# Why does WebStorm flag boolean properties in Vue as not valid in Vue components?

Tags: vue.js, webstorm

WebStorm flags boolean properties in all my Vue components with warnings "xxx is not a valid value". I would like to fix this, but have no idea what I am actually doing wrong.

Here is a minimal example to reproduce the warnings:

Parent component:

```js
<template>
  <child :show="bool1" :disabled="bool2"></child>
</template>

<script>
import Child from './Child.vue';

export default {
  name: "Parent",
  components: {
    Child
  },
  props: {
    bool1: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: true
    }
  },
  data() {return {
    bool2: true
  }}
}
</script>
```

Child component:

```js
<template>
  <div></div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "ChildTest",
  props: {
    show: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: true
    },
    disabled: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: true
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Here is a screenshot how WebStorm flags the boolean property:

[image]

How can I get rid of these warnings?

Answer (score 0):

[WEB-54109](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-54109) is fixed in 2021.3.2, please try upgrading. It works fine for me there:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I am running the latest version (WebStorm 2021.3.2, Build #WS-213.6777.57) and still get the warnings.

Comment: can't reproduce in 3.2, see the updated answer. Try invalidating caches - does the issue persists?

Comment: Invalidating the cache did the trick, thanks.

Comment: The problem occurs again the the latest Webstorm builds.

Comment: works fine for me there, must be something specific to your setup. Did you try invalidating caches?